# Respect negative conditions for advanced collection associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I was trying to use this functionality introduced in [#645](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/pull/645) with conditional 2nd degree `has_many ... through` relationships with little success.

In my case:

- a Course `has_many :user_assigned_content_skills, -> { where(source: 'user') }, class_name: "ContentSkill"`
- and a ContentSkill `belongs_to :skill` and `belongs_to :course`

Then `Course.ransack({user_assigned_content_skills_skill_name_not_cont: 'ruby'}).result.to_sql` returns the following:

`"SELECT courses.* FROM courses LEFT OUTER JOIN content_skills ON content_skills.course_id = courses.id AND content_skills.source = 'user' LEFT OUTER JOIN skills ON skills.id = content_skills.skill_id WHERE (skills.name NOT ILIKE '%ruby%')"`

This means false positives again if a course has multiple content_skills. Any ideas how to retrieve all courses not being associated with a given skill name?

Many thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 1):

You can get ids of courses associated with a given skill name, and then get a list of courses with ids that don't match the previous found. You can even make it as one composite SQL query.

```
Course.where.not(id: Course.ransack({user_assigned_content_skills_skill_name_cont: 'ruby'}).result)
```

This will generate an SQL like this:

```
SELECT courses.* 
FROM courses 
WHERE courses.id NOT IN (
  SELECT courses.id FROM courses 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN content_skills ON content_skills.course_id = courses.id AND content_skills.source = 'user' 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN skills ON skills.id = content_skills.skill_id 
  WHERE (skills.name ILIKE '%ruby%')
)
```